# Hebrews 6:6; could Jesus be crucified again?

Tags: hebrews, christology

Hebrews 6:6; DRB;

> 6 And are fallen away: to be renewed again to penance, **crucifying again to themselves the Son of God,** and making him a mockery.

What is the meaning of **crucifying again to themselves the son of God**?

Is it possible for Jesus Christ to be crucified again?

Are there many copies of the soul of Christ which could be incarnated periodically?

How to solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 5):

Heb 6:4-6, historically, has been one of the most controversial passages with countless arguments, disputes and separations of one group from others, etc.

Benson puts the subject of our current question is context:

> ... to set forth the aggravations of their guilt, *that **they crucify
> to themselves the Son of God afresh**, and put him to open shame*” —
> That is, show themselves to be of the same mind with those that did
> crucify him, and would do it again were it in their power; and do all
> they can to make him contemptible and despised. “It is therefore very
> unreasonable for persons to give way to despair themselves, or to
> drive others to it, by applying to other sins this text, which only
> relates to total apostasy. ...

There is only one "*Christ and Him crucified*" (1 Cor 2:2) and "*only one name under heaven whereby we must be saved - the man Christ Jesus*" (Acts 4:12).

Thus, Heb 6:6 cannot be literally true, but must be understood metaphorically, not about Jesus, but about those whose actions and attitudes are such that they would be capable of crucifying Christ again; but this cannot be done so it is a very grave remark about such people's character indeed.

The Cambridge commentary adds more detail:

> **seeing they crucify** Rather, “while crucifying,” “crucifying as they are doing.” Thus the words imply not only an absolute, but a
> continuous apostasy, for the participle is changed from the past into
> the present tense. While men continue in willful and willing sin they
> preclude all possibility of the action of grace. So long as they cling
> deliberately to their sins, they shut against themselves the open door
> of grace. A drop of water will, as the Rabbis said, suffice to purify
> a man who has accidentally touched a creeping thing, but an ocean will
> not suffice for his cleansing so long as he purposely keeps it held in
> his hand. There is such a thing as “doing despite unto the spirit of
> grace” (Hebrews 10:29).

Barnes reaches a similar conclusion:

> **They crucify to themselves the Son of God afresh** - Our translators have rendered this as if the Greek were - ἀνασταυροῦντας πάλιν
> anastaurountas palin - "crucify again," and so it is rendered by
> Chrysostom, by Tyndale, Coverdale, Beza, Luther, and others. But this
> is not properly the meaning of the Greek. The word ἀνασταυρόω
> anastauroō - is an "intensive" word, and is employed instead of the
> usual word "to crucify" only to denote "emphasis." It means that such
> an act of apostasy would be equivalent to crucifying him in an
> aggravated manner. Of course this is to be taken "figuratively." It
> could not be literally true that they would thus crucify the Redeemer.
> The meaning is, that their conduct would be "as if" they had crucified
> him; it would bear a strong resemblance to the act by which the Lord
> Jesus was publicly rejected and condemned to die. The act of
> crucifying the Son of God was the great crime which outpeers any other
> deed of human guilt. Yet the apostle says that should they who had
> been true Christians fall away and reject him, they would be guilty of
> a similar crime. It would be a public and solemn act of rejecting him.
> It would show that if they had been there they would have joined in
> the cry "crucify him, crucify him." The "intensity and aggravation" of
> such a crime perhaps the apostle meant to indicate by the intensive or
> emphatic ἀνὰ ana in the word ἀνασταυροῦντας anastaurountas.

Answer (score 3):

The question is answered a few pages further on in the book of Hebrews. Turn to chapter 9 and read these crystal-clear statements about Christ's sacrifice and whether it's possible for him to be sacrificed more than once:

> "Christ... by his own blood entered in **once** into the holy place,
> having obtained eternal redemption... For Christ is not entered into
> the holy places made with hands, the figures of the true, but into
> heaven itself, now to appear in the presence of God for us: **nor yet
> that he should offer himself often**, as the high priest entereth into
> the holy place every year with blood of others; For then must he often
> have suffered since the foundation of the world: but now **once** in
> the end of the world hath he appeared to put away sin by the sacrifice
> of himself. And as it is appointed unto men **once** to die, but after
> this the judgment: so Christ was **once** offered to bear the sins of
> man; and unto them that look for him shall he appear the second time
> without sin unto salvation." Hebrews 9:11-12 & 24-28 (Bold mine)

Having established from the same book of the Bible that Christ is only offered sacrificially once, then the earlier bit you quote cannot possibly mean that individuals sacrifice Christ again - not literally, not physically. This bit in 6:6 speaks of how those who falsely profess to be Christians put Christ to shame when they fall away from the faith, to the extent of denying that Christ is the Son of God, the Saviour. ***They effectively "crucify to themselves" the Son of God.***

That phrase, *"to themselves"* shows that ***the application of their falling completely away from the faith of Christ is to themselves***. They have become like those who cried, "Crucify! Crucify!" when Christ was publicly presented as their King. When their cries were heeded, Christ was publicly put to the shame of public crucifixion. Therefore, if later on some individuals deny Christ to the point of disowning him, they are publicly shaming Christ. Their falling away - beyond the realms of repentance - means that they have put themselves on the side of those who cried for Christ's crucifixion when he was once for all time physically nailed to the cross.

The query about Christ incarnating again, via many 'souls' clearly requires a "No" by way of answer, given that 9:27 states that men die once, and after that comes the judgment. Jesus was resurrected with a glorified body that ascended up to heaven, and the next time he appears, it will be to usher in that day of Resurrection and Judgment.

Likewise, **the main question also requires a "No" by way of answer**, given what 9:11-12 & 24-28 state about Christ's once-for-all-time sacrifice of himself. That sacrifice was the one and only perfect sacrifice for sin. If Christ had to be crucified repeatedly thereafter, that would prove his first crucifixion was imperfect - incomplete. No, just before he expired, he cried out, "It is finished!" because that was the ultimate finale to dealing with sin, death and the devil. All three are defeated foes and **nothing that any humans can do can add to the finished work of Christ on the cross.**

Comment: This is an excellent answer too.  +1.